# onMouseOver image swap on php page within a UL

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have a custom php wordpress theme that I was trying to use the onMouseOver event for my page menu, but it isn't working. I'm not that experienced with php, but I can sort thru it with some effort.. Is there another way to get this to work?

the .php

```
<ul class="external-nav">
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory');?>/assets/img/music-icon.png" onMouseOver="this.src='<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory');?>/assets/img/music-icon.png';" onMouseOut="this.src='<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory');?>/assets/img/music-icon.png';" alt="" /></a>
  </li> 
  <li> TWO...</li>
  <li>..three...</li> 
  etc...   
</ul>
```

Is there a way to do this in css or php? All the examples i've seen don't seem easy with multiple images. I have 5 menu options I'd like to to this on.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use property hover in css.
Or it's necessary you can using [javascript in script tag](http://javascript.info/tutorial/adding-script-html), but not inline.
Please create some demo for presenting what you want to have.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in JQuery

```
$('ul.external-nav li a').hover(function(){ 
    $(this).children('img').attr('src','<the_location_of_other_img_here>');
 });
```

If you need to put the original image back, handle the mouseout event

```
$('ul.external-nav li a').mouseout(function(){ 
    $(this).children('img').attr('src','<the_original_image_here>');
 });
```

Hope this helps!